# How to determine and apply "..." on last word within visible div height?

Tags: jquery

I have a `overflow: hidden;` div with a lot of text and with an css inline defined `height`.

This means that X amount of words are visible within that given height.

Is it possible to determine what the last word is within the given `style="height: 145px;"` div height and apply "..." to that word and how would I go about doing this?

Illustrated with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3ab7Lew/)

Example of HTML (where the overflow applies after "Cubilia dolor...")

```
<div class="cut-off" style="height: 145px;">
LOREM IPSUM
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et sem sollicitudin diam nascetur tortor ipsum. Cubilia dolor mi nihil, amet et, amet in sit, aenean metus commodo Lorem ipsum 
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're saying?

Comment: @ochi *"Is it possible to determine what the last word is within the given div height and apply "..." to that word?"* That's the question, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

You could use
`text-overflow: ellipsis;` to accomplish this.

As in

```
.cutoff{
   ...
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out this works for single-lines only (not wrapped, multi-line divs).

Here's another take ([copied on the work from this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLf0Ltf6/2/), so full credit to the author, not me)

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}
.container {
  margin: 30px 0;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 4.5em;
  /*display ellipsis after 3 lines*/
}
.container:before {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  content: '\2026';
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="container">
  But more text here (the same markup structure though): if the text overflows from the clamped    paragraph's height, the ellipse will show.
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Ochi, thanks for the response on this. I tried applying it to my class as in the fiddle,- perhaps im missing something, but nothing seems to happen?

Comment: let me see if I can add a full example

Comment: Alas, it seems like it only works for single lines (not for multi-line divs)... still checking - for now, there is a workaround here http://jsfiddle.net/barney/bmNvs/

Answer (score 1):

sorry that it took a while but I finally got a solution for this excellent question of yours: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8L93pez7/4/)**

```
function ellipsis(elem){
    var html=elem.html(), //get the html of the respective element
        text=html.split('\n'), //split the html by lines and store it into an array
        output=[], //an array to store the final output
        char, //an element to store each charachter to process 
        totalWidth=0, //an array to store the processed width of the text
        charCount=0; //an array to count how many charachters are allowed to be shown in each line
    $.each(text,function(i,v){ //iterating through the array of lines
        charCount=0; //emptying the processed variables
        totalWidth=0; //emptying the processed variables
        for(x=0;x<v.length;x++){ //iterating through each letter of the text
            char=v.substr(x,1); //getting the current charachter
            $('body').append('<span class="char" style="font-size='+elem.css('font-size')+';">'+char+'</span>'); //putting the current charachter inside a span and giving the span the font size of the element so that we can get the width of the charachter
            totalWidth+=$('.char').width(); //adding the width of the charachter to totalWidth to start comparing the total processed width with the element width
            $('.char').remove(); //removing the added span
            if(totalWidth<=elem.width()){ //checking if the total width of charachters surpassed the width of the element
                charCount++; //if not then allowing another charachter to be shown
            }
            else{
                x=v.length; //if it has surpassed it then exiting the for loop
            }
        }
        if(charCount!=v.length){ //checking if the number of allowed charachters is less than the actual line charachter's length
            charCount-=4; //if it is less, taking 3 charachters off (for three dots) and one more for converting the number into the index of the charachter
            output.push(v.substr(0,charCount)+'...'); //showing the allowed number of charachters and adding three dots to the end and storing it to the output array
        }
        else{
            output.push(v); //if it is not less than the actual text then add the actual text to the output
        }
    });
    $.each(output,function(i,v){ //iterating through the output values
        if(v=='')output.splice(i,1); //removing the empty line breaks

    });
    output=output.join('<br>'); //getting the text together and recreating the line breaks by putting a br tag between them
    elem.html(output); //replacing the new processed value with the old value
}
ellipsis($('.cut-off')); //calling the function on the desired element
```

the explanation is in the codes, but feel free to ask any questions that pops up.

also keep in mind that this is just a small function and it doesn't cover all the situations that may come up in a project, but with a little more work on it, it can be perfect for any situation. (this function only works if the element to call this function on only contains text and is not split by br tags )